# Select menu option to display content still not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a menu in the select option. So basically this is a menu that when menu is selected will display the menu content.

I have made it with trigger on click but it still doesn't work properly. Can anyone help me?

```js
function detail(id) {
   $(".content-section").removeClass('shown');
   $("#"+id).addClass('shown');
}
```

```css
.content-section{
  display:none;
}

.content-section.shown{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select__wrapper">
   <option value="banking" onchange="detail('banking')" selected>Banking</option>
   <option value="finance" onchange="detail('finance')">Finance</option>
   <option value="manufacture" onchange="detail('manufacture')">Manufacture</option>
</select>

<div class="content-section shown" id="banking">
  For Banking
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="finance">
  For Finance
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="manufacture">
  For Manufacture
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass option value inside your function i.e : `onchange="detail(this.value)"` and then show required div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function detail(id) {
  $(".content-section").removeClass('shown');
  $("#" + id).addClass('shown');
}
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}

.content-section.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--pass select value-->
<select class="select__wrapper" onchange="detail(this.value)">
  <option value="banking">Banking</option>
  <option value="finance">Finance</option>
  <option value="manufacture">Manufacture</option>
</select>

<div class="content-section shown" id="banking">
  For Banking
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="finance">
  For Finance
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="manufacture">
  For Manufacture
</div>
```

Comment: ohh sorry, if I want to take it based on option value, how is it? i forgot to change the value. I've change my post above

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.select__wrapper').on('change', (e) => {
  $(".content-section").removeClass('shown');
  $("#" + e.target.value).addClass('shown')
})
```

```css
.content-section {
  display: none;
}

.content-section.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select__wrapper">
  <option value="banking" selected>Banking</option>
  <option value="finance">Finance</option>
  <option value="manufacture">Manufacture</option>
</select>

<div class="content-section shown" id="banking">
  For Banking
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="finance">
  For Finance
</div>
<div class="content-section" id="manufacture">
  For Manufacture
</div>
```